# Cannot create new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows-10, concurrent-queue, methodaccessexception

I'm trying to use the [HashLib library](https://hashlib.codeplex.com/) in a Windows 10 app, but it throws an unhandled exception (`System.MethodAccessException`):

> Attempt by method 'HashLib.Hash.TransformStream(System.IO.Stream, Int64)' to access method 'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1..ctor()' failed.

with no further information. The exact line that throws the exception is in the HashLib's source file named [Hash.cs](http://hashlib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#HashLib/Hash.cs) at line 380:

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> queue = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();
```

I can't find any clue regarding this issue [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I just saw that it is supported even in a portable class library so I would think it should work in a normal Windows 10 app, too. The exact same code was successfully used and tested within a WPF application and a Windows 8.1 app without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to convert the stream to byte[], it solves the problem.

```
    public static string MakeHashForFile(Stream fileStream)
    {
        //HashResult hashResult = hashImplementation.ComputeStream(fileStream);
        byte[] bytes = GetBytesFromStream(fileStream);

        HashResult hashResult = hashImplementation.ComputeBytes(bytes);

        return hashResult.ToString().Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
    }

    private static byte[] GetBytesFromStream(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] result;
        using (MemoryStream reader = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(reader);
            result = reader.ToArray();
        }
        return result;
    }
```